# Only overridden methods in Class are being detected

Tags: java, android

I've created a custom adapter to handle a RecyclerView.

For some reason, the only methods that I can call from it after it has been initialised, are the ones that are overridden. Can anyone explain why this is? I have no idea!

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Item> items;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView icon;
        private TextView text;

        public ViewHolder(View item) {
            super(item);

            text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.t);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.i);
        }

        ....
    }

    public CustomAdapter(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup container, int type) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //method content
    }

    //  EVERY METHOD I HAVE WRITTEN FROM HERE ONWARDS GOES UNDETECTED
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

i.e. when I instantiate an instance of the adapter:

```
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(items);
```

and then I try to call `adapter.getCount()`  it does not detect `getCount()`.

`getCount()` does not come up in the autocomplete options when I start to type after 'adapter'. 
`getCount()` shows an error, which just says 'Cannot Resolve Method' and `getCount()` in the `CustomAdapter` class shows that it is never used. This applies to all methods which do not have @override above them.

It is as if the methods don't exist. I cannot call them, but they are there. I am completely baffled!

Comment: Post some sample output of when you attempt to use one of the functions

Comment: I really did not understand what you meant by "UNDETECTED"

Comment: I edited it to try and articulate it better. It is as if the method doesn't exist. I cannot call it. When I instantiate an instance of the above class, and try to call getCount() on it, it is as if the method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(items);
```

to

```
    private CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(items);
```

Comment: YES!!! Thank you so much! I have looked at this for so long and not been able to figure it out!